# C# CheckBoxList checked items to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, checkboxlist

I have a `CheckBoxList` with some items in it and when a user clicks a button, I want the value of the checked text boxes to be added to a single string. I've looked all throughout here for an answer but most of them don't work or produce undesired results. Here is the code I have so far:

```
string selectedItems = CheckBoxList1.Items.???
```

Not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: do this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429655/getting-checkboxlist-item-values   ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `String.Join` with LINQ like:

```
string selectedItems = String.Join(",",
    CheckBoxList1.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(r => r.Selected)
        .Select(r => r.Text));
```

This will give you a comma separated string of all selected items.

Comment: is `OfType` thing is necessary here?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, `OfType` or `Cast` to use LINQ otherwise it is just a `ItemCollection` and you can't use LINQ over it.

Comment: Items is not a collection in this case?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, it is [ItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) which implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>`. Therefore you can't use LINQ over it.

Comment: it means if Type is not known we can't use LInq on it

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, I don't know what you exactly mean, but you can't use LINQ on every type of collection, and if by "Type" you meant `ListItem` in above case then in most of the cases that can be seen through Visual studio intellisense. It will be shown as `ListItemCollection`, hence the type `ListItem`

Comment: See: `By applying OfType<TResult> to a collection that implements IEnumerable, you gain the ability to query the collection by using the standard query operators. For example, specifying a type argument of Object to OfType<TResult> would return an object of type IEnumerable<Object> in C# or IEnumerable(Of Object) in Visual Basic, to which the standard query operators can be applied.` From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 var selected = string.Join(", ", CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                         .Where(li => li.Selected).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());
```

Comment: This will work assuming he wants the `value` instead of the `text`.