# add a value to a checklistbox , if the value does not already exists

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to figure out a way to only add a value to a checklistbox , if the value does not already exists. Is there a way to scan through the text box and then write the value to the `CheckListBox`. At the moment it only tests if the value is not null.

```
var loanItems = chkBoxAssetLoan.Items;
if (cboLoanAssetName.SelectedItem != null)
{
    loanItems.Add(cboLoanAssetName.SelectedItem.ToString(), true);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting CheckBoxList Item values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429655/getting-checkboxlist-item-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [List Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method:

```
 var loanItems = chkBoxAssetLoan.Items;
        if ((cboLoanAssetName.SelectedItem != null)
        {
             if (!loanItems.Contains(cboLoanAssetName.SelectedItem))
            {
            loanItems.Add(cboLoanAssetName.SelectedItem.ToString(), true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method like this  (Assuming that your items are strings)

```
void InsertIfNotExist(CheckedListBox clb, string newItem, bool defaultCheck)
{
    bool result = clb.Items.Cast<string>().Any(x => x == newItem);
    if(!result) clb.Items.Add(newItem, defaultCheck);
}
```

and call it with

```
if (cboLoanAssetName.SelectedItem != null)
{
    InsertIfNotExist(chkBoxAssetLoan, 
                     cboLoanAssetName.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                     true);
}
```